# Can't seem to update my GridLayout in my JFrame. Right now it adds more and more to the frame and I just want to update it

Tags: java, swing, graphics, layout-manager, grid-layout

So this is my runner that runs my entire game. CharacterGame, CharacterChoice and CharacterHead are all classes that contain graphics and paint. I was hoping to be able to call separate parts from these classes into the graphics by the remove and repaint located in one of my button's code. Right now its just updating the Frame with more and more panels instead of removing the old panels and adding these panels into the old panels place. I hope this makes sense as I am a bit new to graphics and may not have thought of the best way to do this. If anyone can shed some light into how to do this, I will be very grateful. Thanks! I've tried everything I can think of... from removeAll methods to repaint. I can't think of anything else to do.

The part not working is located in the ShowButtonDemo() in the choice1Button listener.

```
public class GraphicsRunner extends JFrame
{
   private static final int WIDTH = 1280;
   private static final int HEIGHT = 980;
   private JFrame mainframe;
   private JPanel controlPanel;
   private JPanel headPanel;
   private JPanel gamePanel;
   private JPanel choicePanel;
   private int gameInt = 0;
   private int choiceInt = 0;
   private int endGame = 0;

public GraphicsRunner()
{
    super("Stranded...");

    mainframe = new JFrame();

    mainframe.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    mainframe.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    mainframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0));
    mainframe.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
         public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
            System.exit(0);
         }        
      });
    headPanel = new JPanel();
    gamePanel = new JPanel();
    choicePanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel = new JPanel();
    controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    headPanel = new CharacterHeading();
    gamePanel = new CharacterGame(gameInt);
    choicePanel = new CharacterChoice(choiceInt);

    mainframe.add(headPanel);
    mainframe.add(gamePanel);
    mainframe.add(choicePanel);
    mainframe.add(controlPanel);

    mainframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    mainframe.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main( String args[] )
{
    GraphicsRunner run = new GraphicsRunner();
    run.showButtonDemo();
}

 private void showButtonDemo(){

      JButton choice1Button = new JButton("Choice #1");        
      JButton choice2Button = new JButton("Choice #2");
      JButton choice3Button = new JButton("Choice #3");
      choice3Button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.LEFT);   

      choice1Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             gameInt = gameInt + 1;
             choiceInt = choiceInt + 1;

             gamePanel = new CharacterGame(gameInt);

             //This is the part I am currently working on and I was hoping
             //it would remove the panel instead of just removing the
             //content on the panel...
             mainframe.remove(headPanel);
             mainframe.remove(gamePanel);
             mainframe.remove(choicePanel);
             mainframe.remove(controlPanel);
             mainframe.add(headPanel, 0);
             mainframe.add(gamePanel, 1);
             mainframe.add(choicePanel, 2);
             mainframe.add(controlPanel, 3);
             mainframe.revalidate();
             mainframe.repaint();

             System.out.println(gameInt);
         }          
      });

      controlPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      controlPanel.add(choice1Button);
      controlPanel.add(choice2Button);
      controlPanel.add(choice3Button);       

      mainframe.setVisible(true);  
   }
```

}

Comment: You need to share the content of those files as well, especially because they are manually repainting.

Comment: There are so many errors in your code: 1) Why do you extend JFrame? It is useless and confusing 2) Why do you add a new WindowListener in your button actionListener? Adding it once is enough, and doing it up front upon UI setup makes a lot more sense 3) Why do you have a `Graphics window´ variable? You should NEVER have a Graphics variable 4) Remove all your panels and re-adding them right after that does not do anything 5) You create a new instance of gamePanel without removing first the previous instance. Without an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can hardly help you more;